# T-SQL "not in (select " not working (as expected)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an ordinary one-to-many relation:

```
customer.id = order.customerid
```

I want to find customers who have no associated orders.

I tried:

```sql
-- one record
select * from customers where id = 123

-- no records
select * from orders where customerid = 123

-- NO RECORDS
select * 
from customers 
where id not in (select customerid from orders)

-- many records, as expected.
select * 
from customers 
where not exist (select customerid from orders 
                 where customers.customerid = customer.id)
```

Am I mistaken, or should it work?

Comment: Please provide some sample data which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Is `orders.customerid` nullable? If so, stop using `NOT IN`. (Well, just stop using `NOT IN`, in any case.) https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` does not behave as expected when the in-list contains `NULL` values.

In fact, if any values are `NULL`, then no rows are returned at all.  Remember:  In SQL, `NULL` means "indeterminate" value, not "missing value".  So, if the list contains any `NULL` value then it *might* be equal to a comparison value.

So, `customerid` must be `NULL` in the `orders` table.

For this reason, I strongly recommend that you always use `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery rather than `NOT IN`.

Comment: Indeed; there was a handful of orders with null customerid. 
When I deleted those orders, both queries returned the same number.
There were also orderlines with no corresponding orders. 
I nuked those too.
All were several years old.

Answer (score 2):

I normally do this via a left join that looks for nulls created when the join fails:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM
  customers c
  LEFT JOIN orders o
  ON c.id = o.customerid
WHERE
  o.customerid IS NULL
```

Left join treats the customer table as "solid" and connects orders to it where there is an order with a given customer id and puts nulls where there isn't any matching order, hence the orders side of the relationship has "holes" in the data. By then saying we only want to see the holes (via the where clause), we get a list of "customers with no orders"

As per the comments I've always worked to the rule "do not use IN for lists longer than you'd be prepared to write by hand" but increasingly optimisers are rewriting IN, EXISTS and LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL queries to function identically as they're all recognised patterns of "data in A that has no matching data in B"