# SQL function (NOT IN)

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select, notin

I have problem that with my command because it still return me null rows with value but i dont know why.

If i use this:

```
SELECT count(ad.idfirmy) as id
FROM aadresar as ad
WHERE ad.idfirmy IN (SELECT DISTINCT f.idfirmy FROM ddoklfak f WHERE f.modul = 'FAV' and f.datvyst >= '2019-01-01' and f.datvyst <= '2019-06-30')
```

It´s return me result count 6652

And this command result me 49463.

```
SELECT count(ad.idfirmy) as id
FROM aadresar as ad
```

But this result me 0 rows but i dont know why, because its important for me, what is not in function "NOT IN"

```
SELECT ad.idfirmy as id
FROM aadresar as ad
WHERE ad.idfirmy NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT f.idfirmy FROM ddoklfak f WHERE f.modul = 'FAV' and f.datvyst >= '2019-01-01' and f.datvyst <= '2019-06-30')
```

and result is 0 so why? Please help.

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: How many rows does the subquery return?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085199/11683

Comment: Marko Juvančič -> subquery results is 13029

Comment: GSerg ... Thx, your answer help me so really thx.